# How to pass azure key vault secrets to kubernetes pod using file in helm charts

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-keyvault, kubernetes-secrets

I am using azure key vault to save secrets and use as env variables in deployment.yaml.

but issue is I can see these secrets in azure kubernetes cluster in azure portal.

I read in kubernetes documentation that we can use these variables as file instead of env variables for more secure deployment.

What changes do I need do for achieving this

Here are my helm charts -

SecretProviderClass.yaml

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-keyvault 
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
  - secretName: database-configs
    type: Opaque
    data:
    - objectName: DB-URL
      key: DB-URL

  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true"
    userAssignedIdentityID: {{ .Values.spec.parameters.userAssignedIdentityID }} 
    resourceGroup: {{ .Values.spec.parameters.resourceGroup }} 
    keyvaultName: {{ .Values.spec.parameters.keyvaultName }} 
    tenantId: {{ .Values.spec.parameters.tenantId }} 
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: DB-URL
          objectType: secret
          objectAlias: DB-URL
```

deployment.yaml

```
env:
          - name: DB-URL
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: database-configs
                key: DB-URL
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/mnt/azure"
            name: volume
          - mountPath: "mnt/secrets-store"
            name: secrets-mount
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: azure-managed-disk      
        - name: secrets-mount
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "azure-keyvault"
```

file where helm substituting these values at deployment time-

settings.ini -

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
hot_deployment = false
url = "$env{DB-URL}"

[user_store]
type = "read_only_ldap"
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

I am looking for secure way to use key vault and kubernetes together

Answer (score 1):

I am still looking for a better answer, but this is what I tried.

Deployed a small dummy deployment with all secrets mapped to volume map and environment variable, matching with SecretProviderClass. This creates secrets in K8S.

Now deploying helmchart using those secrets works.

I know this is overhead to deploy unwanted things + it needs to be Highly Available. But could not find any workaround.

Looking for better answer!

Answer (score 0):

The secrets appear in the Azure Portal Kubernetes Resource View because the *SecretProviderClass* `azure-keyvault` has `spec.secretObjects` field. In some cases, you may want to create a Kubernetes Secret to mirror the mounted content. Use the optional `secretObjects` field to define the desired state of the synced Kubernetes secret objects. [Reference](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/configurations/sync-with-k8s-secrets/#how-to-sync-mounted-content-with-kubernetes-secret)

Removing the `spec.secretObjects` will prevent the sync of mounted secret content with the AKS cluster.

---

An environment variable is a dynamic-named value that can affect the way running processes will behave on a computer. They are part of the environment in which a process runs. These should not be confused with files.

The [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#overview-of-secrets) says that a secret can be used with a Pod in 3 ways:

- As [files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod) in a volume mounted on one or more of its containers.
- As [container environment variable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables).
- By the [kubelet when pulling images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-imagepullsecrets) for the Pod.

---

I see that your Helm Chart already has the secret volume mount set up. That leaves the last step from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod):

Modify your image or command line so that the program looks for files in the directory where your secrets would appear (in this case it looks like `/mnt/secrets-store`). Each key in the secret `data` map becomes the filename under `mountPath`.

**Note:** Assuming that you missed `/` in:

> ```
> - mountPath: "mnt/secrets-store"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Do you mean adding in deployment.yaml as - - mountPath: "mnt/secrets-store/DB-URL and doing this for every variable ?

Comment: How do I call them from my settings.ini file ? Thank you

Comment: You do not have to add `mountPath` for each file separately.  The `mountPath`s set up in your deployment.yml would already mount each key from the secret in `/mnt/secrets-store`.

Comment: Since an [INI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) file is an informal standard, how you can reference other files or values from other files depends on the program which is using the configuration file.

Assuming that said `settings.ini` file is part of the application, I would recommend you add the secret file path like `DB-URL-PATH = /mnt/secrets-store/DB-URL` and make the consumer program use text stream manipulation to fetch the secret value from `$DB-URL-PATH`, something like a `readLine()` etc.

Comment: In your `deployment.yml` I would say you need not add anything else. The `spec.volumes[1]` element and the corresponding `spec.containers[].volumeMounts[1]` are already defined in the `deployment.yml` to mount the secrets from `azure-keyvault` *SecretProviderClass* as files in `mnt/secrets-store` inside your resultant Pod. In your app's `INI` file you can set `DB-URL-PATH = mnt/secrets-store/DB-URL` and then the program consuming the configuration from said `INI` file can be modified to read the file whose path is stored in the `DB-URL-PATH` variable in the `INI` file to get the secret data.